# V8 on JBoss + Centos(6/7)

Tags: centos, centos6, centos7, jboss

I want to use the [Google V8](https://github.com/v8/v8) js engine on my JBoss server that runs on a `centos6` or `centos7` machine.

I fount [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) which is supposed to take care of the `JNI` aspect, but from the project page I understand that I need to have a build version of `V8` installed on the machine to use it.

I tried to follow the instructions in the project to compile it with no success.

Here is the script that I ran on `centos7` to make it work:

```
yum install -y git
git clone https://github.com/v8/v8.git
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
cd v8
gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8
gclient sync
export PYTHONPATH="/root/test/v8/v8/build/" # to include gn_helpers
tools/dev/v8gen.py arm64.release            # pretty sure it's the right one, but tried all of the options and it doesn't work
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 304, in <module>
    sys.exit(gen.main())
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 298, in main
    return self._options.func()
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 166, in cmd_gen
    gn_outdir,
  File "tools/dev/v8gen.py", line 208, in _call_cmd
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/python', '-u', 'tools/mb/mb.py', 'gen', '-f', 'infra/mb/mb_config.pyl', '-m', 'developer_default', '-b', 'arm64.release', 'out.gn/arm64.release']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

1. Can it be done?
2. On which platform?
3. Where can I find the instructions on how to do it?

Comment: Why not just install v8 from the EPEL?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sounds good, but how do I do that? will it work with `J2V8`?

Comment: The same as anything else? `yum install v8 v8-devel`

Comment: Got `No package v8 available` and `No package v8-devel available`

Comment: Also, made sure that `EPEL` is installed with `sudo yum install epel-release`

Comment: Is this the same broken system you posted about before? You should fix your repos first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48429/discussion-between-algosub-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't know what broken system you're talking about, especially since I think this is the first question I posted in 'server fault', but I'll be happy if you join me in the chat